# A read only (immutable) serializeable class

Tags: c#, immutability

I've designed a class that has with two properties - as string type and a list of objects.  I'm loading some xml and deserializing it into an instance of the class, which works very well.  What I want is for everything about each instance to be immutable.  These classes are exposed as an API, and for integrity, I don't want values of the object to be changed.  If a programmer wants something different they should be creating new instances and setting the values then.

Normally I would do this with the ReadOnlyCollection and readonly properties, but that messes up the deserialization.  What kinds of things can I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not worth polluting your domain model just be be more xml serializer friendly so you can implement [ISerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and write your own serialization routine for any collection that is not serialization friendly.

```
void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) in your class. That way, when the class is deserialized a special constructor is called and you can keep your class truly immutable

Answer (score 0):

Implement the ISerializable interface and do that manually